# IE10 Design Guidelines for Touch Input?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, mobile, windows-8, microsoft-metro, internet-explorer-10

I'm working on a new Asp.Mvc3 application that will go line about the same time as Windows 8/IE10 is released.  We are still trying to finalize our overall design.

My question is: are there any html design guidelines for using IE10 in Windows 8 Metro?  In particular, how to handle touch inputs.  Is it as simple as just following the general mobile guidelines, like jQuery mobile.

Any advice would be useful as I'm unable to get access to a PC running Windows 8 developer edition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at:

[8 traits of great Metro style apps](http://channel9.msdn.com/events/BUILD/BUILD2011/BPS-1004)

[Designing Metro style apps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465427%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Could you expand on this answer, please? As it stands it's a very weak answer consisting only of two links to external sources.